# Return scores of each ID based on its 2 months old record

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and am facing this challenge where I need to take the scores of IDs based on 2 month old record respectively. To put it in simple demo:

| APP Date | ID | Score 1 | Score 2 | Score 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-31 | 121 | 254 | 312 | 789 |
| 2022-09-30 | 121 | 261 | 542 | 774 |
| 2022-08-31 | 121 | 424 | 432 | 786 |
| 2022-07-30 | 121 | 322 | 764 | 963 |

I applied the max function to return the scores based on max APP Date but can't seem to figure out a way to return records that are 2 months old. Based on today's date (November 07) I am expecting to see the below result:

| APP Date | ID | Score 1 | Score 2 | Score 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-30 | 121 | 261 | 542 | 774 |

Note: All APP Dates are based on month end.
Could anyone please guide me with this? Thanks in advance all!

Query I have used (until now):

```
with maxdate as ( 
    select ID, max([APP_DATE]) as maxdate 
    from [Table]
    where ID is not null group by ID 
) 
SELECT [APP_DATE],
    a.ID,
    Score 1,
    Score 2,
    Score 3 
FROM [Table] a 
join maxdate md on a.ID = md.ID and maxdate = a.[APP_DATE]
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running. Date functions are highly vendor-speciic. Also, please show us the query you have so far, even if it is not 100% working.

Comment: I"ll give you a hint. Use the `where` clause to filter on records that are within 2 months. e.g. `WHERE ((`APPDATE` >= '2022-09-01 00:00:00')`

Comment: Hi @GMB, the query I am running now is as below:

with  maxdate as (

select ID, max([APP_DATE]) as maxdate from [Table]

where ID is not null 

group by ID

)
SELECT [APP_DATE]
,a.ID
,Score 1
, Score 2
,Score 3 FROM [Table] a 
join maxdate md on a.ID = md.ID and maxdate = a.[APP_DATE]
ORDER BY ID

Answer (score 0):

may be below query help you.:

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM score
WHERE appdate <= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
order by appdate desc
```